# Is there a way to allow command in sudo based on the current working directory?

Tags: sudo

I want sudo to allow me to run a command when my current working directory is, for example, /tmp. Example usage is removing files from /tmp directory, so I am in /tmp ($PWD of shell == /tmp), then I can run, rm -v someuseless.bin (someuseless.bin of course not belongs to me, so I can't remove it).
If it is impossible (I can't find references in sudo manuals), then why? Maybe there is a security violation that I did not spotted here. Thanks.

Comment: I'd also usggest looking after linux ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely embed the `$cwd` in sudoers, to allow someone only to remove a file under a particular directory, but you're going the wrong way about it.  The way to do what you want is to use absolute paths in `sudoers`, eg

```
orc       ALL=(ALL) /bin/rm /tmp/someuseless.bin
```

Comment: Is $cwd here a shell variable, or something related to sudoers? The second way I just using now (embedding absolute paths), but there is no only /tmp directory that I want to use in that way (some other directory with four of five levels of names, so it is long to type it)

Comment: It's shell shorthand for "the current working directory".  The way you were using is the right way; you're going to have to list out all the working directories you want to be valid anyway, so there's no harm in listing them in the sudo'ed commands list.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script which checks for the current directory, then give sudo rights to run that script.

/usr/local/bin/cwddostuff.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$CWD" != "/tmp" ]; then
   exit 1
fi

echo do your stuff
```

/etc/sudoers:

```
user       ALL=(ALL) /usr/local/bin/cwddostuff.sh
```

But **beware** doing this is dangerous, as now you need to check also if all arguments are ok (for example, the user might be in /tmp, but run 'rm -rf /').

The best way is to do as MadHatter told, explicitly add the paths the user is allowed to remove, or as Kwaio suggested, set ACLs on the directories.